# in nodejs. how can I "terminate" the previous process started by on.connection if I refreshed the page?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

in the on.connection I started a process which will execute several shell commands in a row and parse the stdout. This process takes about 10 seconds to receive all the information it needs for this page. 
But what if I refreshed the page within this 10 seconds? How can I terminated the previous process so the on.connection will start without the influence from the stdout message caused by the previous process?

```
on.connnection(){
    async function(){
        let res = await run_cmd('xxxx')
        res = parse_first_res(res)
        res = await run_cmd('zzz' + res)
        res = parse_second_res('xxyy' + res)
        ....
    }
}
```

I thought about semaphore, but it is just not very neat.

Comment: Please could you provide some sample code to clearly explain the problem and requirement.

Comment: @Don Thank you. I updated the code. I do not have the source code in my hand but it runs basically the same.

Comment: To stop any previous process you'll need a handle to the process or some kind of a cancellation token that when called would kill the process. I.e. you'll need to refactor your `run_cmd` function. Without seeing much of the code it's difficult to propose a solution. Either way, you'll eventually need to call the kill method on the process to stop it.

Comment: @Don The run_cmd is simply a child_process.exec(), while I wrapped it and let it run synchronously and return a promise object. So how can I kill it in this case?